# How to use dynamic_cast in if statement

Tags: c++, class, base-class, dynamic-cast

So I've got a simple task to do. There are 3 classes derived from one base class. They're quite simple and will be provided below.
What I need to do is create a new class called `PolymorphicAnimal`, that'll be able to behave just as any other `animal` derived from the `Animal` base class.
To be exact, all they need to do is display the right text after method `SoundOff` is called. I'm guessing I need to use `dynamic_cast` here. My question is, what's the right syntax for using `dynamic_cast` as an `if` statement, and do all the derived classes need to have at least one virtual method as well?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Animal {
public:
virtual std::string SoundOff() = 0;
};

class Dog : public Animal {
std::string SoundOff() override { return "Woof"; }
};

class Cat : public Animal {
std::string SoundOff() override { return "Meow"; }
};

class Cow : public Animal {
std::string SoundOff() override { return "Muu"; }
};

class PolymorphicAnimal : public Animal {
std::string sound;
public:
PolymorphicAnimal(const Animal &a) {
    if(std::dynamic_cast<Cat*>(a))
}
};
```

The line `if(std::dynamic_cast...` generates compiler errors:

`syntax error '<', illegal token on the right side of ::` and `expected an identifier`

Comment: whats the problem with `if(std::dynamic_cast<Cat*>(a))`?

Comment: @stetoc syntax error '<', illegal token on the right side of ::, and expected an indentifier (in the line with `dynamic_cast`)

Comment: you cannot cast object to pointer, you need to basically add `&` before `a` in your dynamic cast so you pass address of object

Comment: Use `if(std::dynamic_cast<Cat*>(&a)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++ you can declare a variable in the conditional of an `if`, which is a powerful feature that you can exploit here. So,

```
if (auto kitty = dynamic_cast<const Cat*>(&a)){
    // kitty is not nullptr
}
```

Notes:

1. `dynamic_cast` is a *keyword*; do drop the `std::`
2. I've used a pointer `dynamic_cast`. The reference alternative is impractical as you can't, in general, expect an implicit conversion of a reference type to a `bool` type, and if a reference cast fails an exception is thrown.

Comment: I was trying your code, and it wouldn't work, then I realized I'm missing `const`, and just then it worked. This is exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Also, just being curios, why wouldn't it work without `const`

Comment: @MelvinBrooks: Out of interest, what is the syntax that didn't work?

Comment: Ah I see, yes you need `<const Cat*>` in the `dynamic_cast` since `dynamic_cast` is not allowed to cast away const-ness, `const_cast` is required for that, with all the cautions that go along with such a cast.

Comment: @Bathsheba I think because `Cat` is passed in as a `const` reference.

Comment: @PaulSanders: Absolutely!

Comment: @Bathsheba tada!

Answer (score 5):

`dynamic_cast` is almost always a hack.

Why don't you add another virtual method to `Animal`, and then have `Dog`, `Cat` and `Cow` override it in the usual way?  Or don't you control these classes?

Comment: This is a task that usually comes on my exam and carries a nice amount of points for what it is, and the professor expects as to show that we know when and how to use `dynamic_cast`

Comment: OK, well, if you have no choice...  So now you know how, and the 'when' is ... 'never' :)

Comment: ͏+͏1͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏ Nothing wrong with curve-ball answers if they contain excellent advice, which this one does.

Comment: @Bathsheba Thanks, I'm honoured. Curve-ball answers are a bit of a trademark of mine.  Doesn't always work, but, well, you know.

Comment: And you can of course now easily add classes `Badger`, `Gerbil` and `Weasel`.

Answer (score 0):

Whereas virtual methods or visitor might be more appropriated, you might use something like:

```
PolymorphicAnimal(const Animal &a) {
    if (const auto* cat = dynamic_cast<const Cat*>(&a)) {
        // use cat
    } else if (const auto* dog = dynamic_cast<const Dog*>(&a)) {
        // use dog
    } // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very unclear what exactly the PolymorphicAnimal should do. Somehow you need to tell PolymorphicAnimal how to behave, right? So, I'm guessing it's more like a Factory than a derived class.

Something like this:

```
class PolymorphicAnimal : Animal
{
private:
    Animal *animal;
public:
    PolymorphicAnimal(int type)
    {
        if (type == Type_Cat) // Type_Cat is an enum for example
        {
            animal = new Cat();
        }
        // ...add other types here
    }
    std::string SoundOff()
    {
        return animal->SoundOff();
    }
}
```

Normally, you shouldn't need to do if (something dynamic_cast something) in a normal program.